# unable to hit the CheckBox_CheckedChanged event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to check one condition when i m checking a particular checkbox.below is the code

```
Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox4.Checked Then
            check_CL()
        End If
```

i put one debugger to check whether the control is going to this event or not but it's not going.please tell me what is the problem..

Comment: Please show that control from the `.Designer.cs` page..

Comment: it's a winform application...how to show the designer.cs..??

Comment: You must not have added registered the event. Register the event from designer. Verify it from your Designer>Properties>Events section

Comment: Open the Form in Designer view and double click on the CheckBox4 control. This will cause VB to focus on the Code Behind file and will even create a Sub for the Event. Make sure you put your code there

Comment: I wrote the code after double clicking only..@Ahmad San

Answer (score 0):

From your arguments it looks that you have performed appropriate steps. I would suggest that you should look for this piece of code:

```
   RemoveHandler CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox4_CheckedChanged
```

It is possible that you have unregistered handler somewhere in code either in `.vb` or `.designer.vb`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the full code to see if it works?

```
If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
  check_CL()
End If
```

Comment: ya..and my problem is its not hitting the event itself..executing the inside statement is not a concern...